# fix `Missing frozen string literal comment` issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop, code-climate, ruby-2.3

I created a new migration, it looks like this one:

```
class AddCommentsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :comments, :text
  end
end
```

Now with Code Climate I am warned of an issue:
`Missing frozen string literal comment.`

I tried to fix it like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class AddCommentsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :comments, :text
  end
end
```

**But I still have the same issue. How can I solve it?** Thanks.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Have you investigated locally with the Code Climate CLI or rubocop?

Answer (score 11):

I experienced the same problem. Rubocop was working fine before but suddenly it started acting up. I read through their configuration options on github and saw the particular property that is messing with your code.
The property can be found here: [FrozenStringLiteral](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/41a8249b3595cc8656b823d50b2abe38206fd09a/config/default.yml#L3739).

To silence this warning, you only need to add this to your `rubocop.yml` file

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: false
```

Comment: This change just silences the warning. The linked page describes the right solution: `Add the frozen_string_literal comment to the top of files to help transition to frozen string literals by default.`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an empty line below the string literal line fixed it for me.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module FooBar
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added your changes to the staging area before trying to run Rubocop again. I had the same problem and that solved it for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31653064)

Answer (score 0):

Run bundle exec rubocop --parallel -A (AUTO FIX)

AND

RUN AGAIN bundle exec rubocop --parallel OR rubocop

Try....